Dayjs Getting incorrect timestamp & date
Dayjs object shows correct date & time but when converting it to iso string or timestamp. i am getting incorrect values.
here is the code -
console.log("updated date",
      date, date.valueOf(),
      date.toISOString(),
    );


i am expecting correct date time & timestamp values

Please share the expected (or correct) results, In my test I do no see anything unexpected ( https://jsfiddle.net/ufcomxjv/ )
